# automatically put android widget on lock screen under certain conditions

Tags: android, android-widget, lockscreen

I am making an mp3 player for myself and have created a homescreen widget for it.  I can add it to my lock screen by virtue of having included:

```
android:widgetCategory="keyguard|home_screen"
```

in my appwidget provider.  This doesn't quite meet my requirements for two reasons.  1) it's ALWAYS there whether I want it or not (only want it when music is playing) and 2) it doesn't seem to work very well, I have to unlock the widget to enable it and even then the buttons work sporadically.

The phone I have (HTC One) came stock with an mp3 player that puts itself on my lock screen automatically when music is playing and removes itself when it's not.  Unfortunately, this is the only thing I like about this mp3 player thus my reasoning for writing my own.  I therefore know that this can be done, I just have run the well dry in terms of searching for how to do it.  I'm on android 4.3 with my HTC One and I really only care about this application working for myself (I have no intention of putting it on the store or anything).

Given that information, can someone provide some assistance/direction of how I can accomplish what I want?  To reiterate, when music is playing I want my widget to appear on the lock screen and have the buttons available w/o needing to swipe that screen at all (just like the stock player).  When music is stopped/paused, I want that widget removed from the lock screen (also just like the stock player).

TIA

Comment: First, the integrated MP3 stuff is probably a feature of the lockscreen itself, and is not necessarily subject to the limitations of what SDK developers can do. Second, having it removed seems like an odd choice -- wouldn't you want to be able to *start* music playback from the lockscreen? Beyond that, you cannot add or remove a lockscreen widget yourself, though you are welcome to update the UI of your lockscreen widget (e.g., remove all buttons).

Comment: @CommonsWare `having it removed seems like an odd choice` The stock player OP mentions (and every other audio player I've used) performs in this manner, and only exists on the lock screen if playback has already begun, *or* if a setting is used to start the player when the headphone jack is plugged in.

Comment: bummer...so doesn't sound like I'll be able to accomplish what I want then.  At worst, I'd still like to be able to manually add my widget to the lock screen and have it work w/o having to drag on it to "unlock the widget itself".  Is that a possibility?  Also, any idea why the buttons only work some of the time?